# Add figcaption name to h2

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to add chosen figcaption to h2.
Here is a code

```
<div id="custom_form">

  <h2>Cars</h2>

  <div class="models">
    <div class="sections" onclick="buyclick1()">
      <img src="2.png" width="200px" ;>
      <figcaption>GX</figcaption>
    </div>
    <div class="sections" onclick="buyclick1()">
      <img src=" 3.png " width="200px ">
      <figcaption>GT</figcaption>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I add figcaption name to h2, consider that it shoud depends on what person click on?
It should look like in online shop where you toggle between categories and subcategories of a product (# Cars>GT>Another categorie).

Comment: Have you tried anything? It appears as though you've defined a `buyclick1` function; please show us that function's code.

Comment: its another code that calls a new div section and remove this one

Comment: In what way do you want the `<figcaption>` name added to the `<h2>` element? Also, what name? Do you mean the text?

Comment: For example, Cars>GT>Another categorie. Maybe it could go without figcaption and put a name of the categorie in div, problem is I dont know how to append it to h2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following way:

```js
var t = document.querySelector('h2').textContent;
function buyclick1(el){
  var h2El = document.querySelector('h2');
  h2El.textContent = t;
  var caption = el.children[1].textContent;
  h2El.textContent += ' >> ' + caption;
}
```

```html
<div id="custom_form">

  <h2>Cars</h2>

  <div class="models">
    <div class="sections"  onclick="buyclick1(this)">
      <img src="2.png"  width="200px";>
      <figcaption>GX</figcaption>     
    </div>          
    <div class="sections"  onclick="buyclick1(this)">                
      <img src="3.png"  width="200px">

      <figcaption>GT</figcaption>

    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: It works fine, but there is a function  onclick on the sections that remove this div, and replace it by another div but with the same structure. So, that why I guess it doesn't work in my code

Comment: function buyclick1() {
    div = document.getElementById('custom_form1');
    div.style.display = "block";
var elem = document.getElementById('custom_form');
 elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);

}

Comment: @ADli, it is really difficult answer question when you specify only part of the code. You can try combine the code in the function body.......though you do not have any element with id `custom_form1` in the HTML which will leads to an error.............

Comment: So, I decided that problem, now it works, but how can I add one more caregorie to this? Like 1>>2>>3? Cause while I click on 3 it replacing with 2 and become 1>>3.